# Is this necessary

Tags: python

I'm still semi new to python and all over the place in source code, I see this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What does it mean exactly? Is it something I should be using in every program I write or just occasionally?

Comment: Quick everybody! Close this as duplicate

Comment: Brr, don't stir the horses.

Comment: was that quick enough? :)

Comment: if you import your code as a module, your code will execute your main() code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and explanation